# CentOS各種設定ファイルのバックアップについて。どうやってどこへ保存するのですか？

Tags: centos

CentOS各種設定ファイルや、設定ファイルを格納しているディレクトリのバックアップは、一般的にはどこへどうやって行うのですか？
推奨されているやり方があれば知りたい。

これまで
コピー後、ファイル名やデイリクトリ名を変更して、同じ場所へ保存していました。

疑問に思ったきっかけ
/etc/nginx/conf.d/内を一括置換する前に、念のためバックアップを取得しておこうと思い、コピー後ディレクトリ名だけを変更して同じ場所に保存したら、よく分からない状態になりました。恐らく、/etc/nginx/conf.d/ ディレクトリ内の .conf 拡張子を持つすべてのファイルが読み込まれているためだと思うのですが、confファイルは件数が多いので、こういうときにはどうすればよいのか知りたく質問しました。

違う場所に保存？
/etc/nginx/conf.d/ ディレクトリのバックアップを保存することが推奨されているようなディレクトリはありますか？

保存方法を変更？
それとも圧縮したりして、同じところに保存するのですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

バックアップってのは目的によりどこに保存すべきか違います。

- 設定ミス等で動作しなくなったとき簡単に元に戻す目的

今なら断然ソースコード管理ツールを使います。正しく動いていた時の設定ファイル一式を取り出すことが一瞬でできるわけです。差分も自動管理してくれるし、手動でやる漏れもないし、サイコーっすね。つまり「コピーすることでバックアップする」ことはしません。

デプロイツールの都合とかセキュリティ管理の都合とか、今回のように設定ファイルを置くディレクトリ以下は何もかもロードするとか、そういう事情がある場合には設定ファイルのあるディレクトリとは別ディレクトリにて `git` (や `hg` ) で管理すればよいでしょう。攻撃者から簡単に見つからない場所ならどこでも問題ないです。

- 記憶装置のクラッシュ時に復元時間を最短にする目的
- ランサムウエア被害にあったとき復元時間を最短にする目的

同一記憶装置内に置いていては何の意味もないので別の記憶装置にコピーします。前者ならオンラインバックアップで十分、つまり接続済みいつでもアクセスできる別装置が便利です。後者ならオフラインにできる装置でなければなりません。まあ普通に D2D2T みたいな構成にしてテープ装置にバックアップするのが正しいでしょう。テープメディアを抜いておけばオフラインにできます。

上記２つは矛盾しませんので、設定ファイル群のリポジトリ `.git` 等ごとテープ装置にバックアップする、ってのがよいでしょう。

Comment: 「ソースコード管理ツール」なるほど。質問時点では思いつきませんでした。参考になりました

Answer (score 1):

re9 さんの質問は、実際に起きている問題に対して、質問の組み立てが微妙に的外れなもの (XY 問題) になっている気がします。

---

#### 設定ファイルのバックアップについて

OS (Linux) 全般の話として、バックアップ先として特に既定のディレクトリは決まっていないと思います。

簡易的なバックアップ (=ひとつ前の状態を保存しておく) 程度であれば、元のファイルと同じディレクトリに別名で保存することも多いと思います。

#### Nginx での設定ファイルの扱い

Nginx では `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` 以下にある `*.conf` という拡張子のファイルをすべて読み込みます。

> ```
> http {
>     include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
>     include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
> }
> ```

(同じ web サーバの Apache も似たような仕組みで Include で外部ファイルを読み込みます)

拡張子で判断するので、ここに前述のバックアップもファイル名が `*.conf` で終わっていると読み込まれてしまいます。ですので、バックアップファイルは `*.conf.bak` とか `*.conf.OLD` など別の拡張子にする必要があるでしょう。
(何かで見かけたのは `*.conf.disabled` のようなサフィックスを付けている例もあった気がします)

参考:
[【Nginx】設定ファイルとは（nginx.conf、conf.d、sites-available、uwsgi_paramsなど）](https://office54.net/iot/linux/nginx-setting-file)